# Second M2 ssd is not recognized if ubuntu is booted under UEFI

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, ssd

I accidentally installed ubuntu 6 months ago under legacy and since then I have been loading windows and ubuntu sing legacy boot. I got a new m2 ssd recently and installed in Windows and decided to more ubuntu from legacy to UEFI.

Since I installed ubuntu under UEFI, it does not recognize the second m2 SSD, however, if I boot with legacy it does recognize it.

Is there any solution for ubuntu to recognize second ssd once loading with UEFI?

---

Update 1:

- Here is the information of the machine:[SSD drive info picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyMkJ.png)
  and [drive partition picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHSZl.png). There are two drives: drives 0 which has windows and ubuntu installed on it and the second drive which was formatted in window and has problem on ubuntu and ubuntu does not recognize it once booted under UEFI. The main drive has EFI partition at the beginning burt second drive does not have the EFI drive. Do you think that partition is causing it?
- Machine is a precision 5520 with i7 cpu and nVIDIA 1200 graphic.
- I have not updated UEFI. How can I update UEFI? Any link or instruction on how to update  UEFI?
- Drives are set to RAID as far as I looked at it on BIOS. There are AHCI and another option available but once I tried to change it to AHCI there was a warning saying that my computer might completely stop working so I did not do it. If I have to change to AHCI how can I do it safely?
- Windows was shut down in all cases and fast start and hibernate were disabled in windows. here is photo from windows: [fast start and hibernate in windows disabled photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9svG.png).

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and firmware on your SSDs? Are drives set for AHCI in UEFI, not IDE, RAID nor Intel RST? What brand/model system? IF other SSD is Windows and you have Fast start or hibernation on, partitions will not be visible. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: Please read my update in the following.

Comment: You should post your updates as additional info in your original question, not as an answer. You must change to AHCI, but have to install AHCI drivers into Windows first. Dell now lets you update UEFI using LInux but most do it directly with Dell. Dell Precision 5820 with PCI NVME SSD UEFI update & SSD firmware update
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2402254
 & Dell update UEFI/BIOS from Linux
https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln171755/updating-the-dell-bios-in-linux-and-ubuntu-environments?lang=en

Comment: Thank you for the info. Let me try it and keep you updated.

Comment: What is causing the second SSD to be readable in legacy mode but not in UEFI?

Comment: I just did and followed the following steps:
1. Run MSCONFIG
2. Enable Safe Boot (minimal)
3. Reboot into UEFI/BIOS and change to AHCI
4. Boot up into safe mode
5. Run MSCONFIG and disable Safe Boot.
6. Reboot. and it worked. My second drive is not recognized in ubuntu. Thank you!

Comment: As a suggestion, do you suggest installing ubuntu on the second SSD and keep windows on the first one OR keep both on the first SSD and use the second SSD for data storage and program files?

Comment: Since both are SSD, it really is up to you. I generally prefer to keep them separate, but the only easy way to do that with UEFI is to disconnect or turn off in UEFI (if possible) the Windows drive. Otherwise you have to partition in advance, and be sure to include ESP on Ubuntu drive. but grub will install to Windows' drive's ESP. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu